# Lazy load items in an ngRepeat collection in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova

How do I handle large collections of `ng-repeat` in AngularJS?

I am thinking about the cancellation of downloading process once the user decides to switch to another controller.

To display images I use:

```
<ul class="thumbnails">
    <li ng-repeat="photo in photosFound.data track by $index" >
        <a prettyp class="thumbnail" ng-href="{{domain}}/{{photo.thumb}}" rel="prettyPhoto[main]">
            <img class="group1" ng-src="{{domain}}/{{photo.image}}" />
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Is there a way to cancel the download of all 150 images once the user decides to change the controller they're in?

Comment: This is probably automatic by the browser once a `<img>` tag is no longer in the DOM

Comment: Can't prevent the requests once they have been made. Use pagination to show fewer results and can improve performance using one way binding

Comment: @charlietfl it right. but as an option you could try to check it the service worker technology that can 'proxy' requests - https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2016/02/making-a-service-worker/ is applicable

Comment: are you using Ionic? If so; you should realize this is a known issue, and the fix is to use `collection-repeat`: http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/collectionRepeat/

Comment: Angular Material has a virtual repeat directive that should work well here. https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/virtualRepeat

Comment: to avoid large data sets you should use pagination

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like ui scroller (https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-scroll) which will de-render anything outside of the scrollable viewport ... this will help you with really large sets of data in ng-repeat.

Regarding your second question: you can cancel open $http requests using a promise. This guy does a pretty good job of describing how you go about accomplishing this. http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2014/04/24/canceling-http-requests-in-angularjs.aspx

Comment: That is the most confusing angular module i have yet had to deal with. Seriously, what is this? for (i = j = ref = index, ref1 = index + count - 1; ref <= ref1 ? j <= ref1 : j >= ref1; i = ref <= ref1 ? ++j : --j) { That's for setting your source data?!